# ACF block notice error block type is already registered - Showing error for all the block types

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields PRO 6.0.6 version and when I enable debug option to true to fix the debug errors. I am facing error with ACF as shown below :

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: This is probably one for ACF support as they'll know the specifics here - you're a pro customer after all - but it sounds like you're calling something twice or triggering an action twice that registers the block types. In the first instance I think you want to try and track that down in the code, but you could also modify the point that raises that error to log the stack trace too in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Function `acf_register_block_type` is called by `acf_register_block`. When you know that you can search your code for `acf_register_block(` and remove duplicated block declaration.